# Pass List of Objects from Android to RESTful Webservice

Tags: java, android, rest

Using Luke's [RestClient](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/) for Android and calling it like this:

```
    String baseurlString = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/WebTest/jaxrs/ws/testlist";
    RestClient client = new RestClient(baseurlString);

    String list = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?><pairs><pair><_id>1</_id><_version>12</_version></pair></pairs>";
    client.AddParam("list", list);
    client.AddHeader(ContentType, MediaType.UrlEncoded);

    try
    {
        client.Execute(RequestMethod.POST);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String responseString = client.getResponse();
```

To Rest method like this:

```
@POST
@Path("testlist")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Produces("application/xml")
public List<Pair> insertList(@FormParam("list") List<Pair> pairs)
{
    return pairs;
}
```

Since without List works as expected:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Pair insertValue(@FormParam("pair") Pair pair)
{
    return pair;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request